# Is a view "reloaded" when you have left it?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, xcode8

I have a view controller. It has some data and values in it. Then it presents modally to another view and moves around and some stuff happens. Then at some point, you `self.dismissViewController()`. Once back at the original view, can I count on the original data being there? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They will not be affected unless you specifically write code to do that for you.

For example, if you call a network request in the `viewDidLoad()` and add the data to some views, labels, etc. Then you leave that ViewController and come back, nothing will change, i.e., the network request will not be called again.

If you do want to change values in the ViewController every time it appears, use the `viewDidAppear()` delegate method.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

for reloading view on dismiss you must use `viewWillAppear()` because this working every time before rendering view

Comment: This isn't what I'm asking. I am asking if I have values in a view, and I leave and return to that view through a modal presentation, will the values be affected?

Comment: In this case values will be affected

Comment: Any suggestions on the best way of saving these values?

Answer (score 0):

calling `dismissViewController` will remove the viewController. If you do not have a strong reference to the view controller stored elsewhere, dismissing it releases the memory associated with it.

If the presented view controller must return data to the presenting view controller, use the delegation design pattern to facilitate the transfer.

So if the data was not modified in the presented controller then it will be the same then you can depend on it

reference: [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/PresentingaViewController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH14-SW10)

Comment: I believe @GraysonM is speaking of the initial ViewController, not the one that is dismissed.

Comment: @CalebKleveter i was answering "can I count on the original data being there?" so it will be there but is it correct data?